Problem with original Animation after Retargeting
So my base idea is that Ive got a rigged Character which already has a walking animation. Now I want to build the base on that and downloaded a mixamo turn animation, and retargeted it so my Character. This process works just fine, but then if I try to switch the action back to my original walking animation, it's all messed up after the retargeting process. All I want is my Character ready to play all Animations on it so I can use it in Unity. And of course keep my original walk cycle. Thanks for your time.
